# Как превратить строку в ресурс

Tags: java, android

Активность получает строку (R.drawable.che3) методом `final String get_image = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE);` Вопрос как мне превратить эту строку в ресурс (изображение или ссылку на ресурс) вот пример под этот метод

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cheese_1);
```

-->

```
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
            imageView.setImageResource(EXTRA_IMAGE);
```

или так попонятнее о чем я `imageView.setImageResource("R.drawable." + EXTRA_IMAGE )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам известен айди ресурса, то лучше передавать его в int'е:

```
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_IMAGE", R.id.someres);
getIntent().getIntExtra("EXTRA_IMAGE", 0);
```

А если вам известна только строка "someres", то преобразовать строку в ресурс можно так:

```
private int getResourceByName(String res) {
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    return getResources().getIdentifier(res, "drawable", packageName);
}
```

---

```
imageView.setImageResource(getResourceByName(EXTRA_IMAGE));
```

Comment: ,ресурсы парсятся через json в string я могу писать любое имя строки, не подскажешь как лучше поступить? эту строку нужно парсить в инт или можно при передаче указать

Comment: @jon, тогда только второй вариант

Comment: ,а этот способ подойдет? String mString = "R.id.someres"; // строка
int mInt = Integer.parseInt(mString); , но у меня почему то крашится

Comment: @jon, так не выйдет